# custom event is not triggered on dojo widget

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

I have dojo Custom widget.

I need to emit a event from the custom widget, 
this the code where I have added the event listener

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            parseOnLoad: true,
            isDebug : true,
            packages:[
                {   name:"custom",
                    location:"/Test/js"
                }
            ]
        };
    </script>
    <script src="//localhost:8080/dojo1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    require(["custom/MyWidget","dojo/on","dojo/dom-construct","dojo/_base/window","dojo/domReady!"],function(MyWidget,on,domconstruct,window){
        var mywidget = new MyWidget();
        mywidget.startup();
        domconstruct.place(mywidget.domNode,window.body(),"after");


        on(mywidget,"customevent",function(data){
            console.log( " received notification "+data );
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and widget as below

```javascript
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./widget.html",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/_base/lang"
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin, template,on,lang) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        //  your custom code goes here
        _onClick:function()
        {

        },

        postCreate : function ()
        {
            on(this.searchtextbox,"click",lang.hitch(this,"sendEvent"));

        },
        sendEvent : function(event)
        {
            console.log( "Click event in widget "+event );
            this.emit("customevent",event.x)
        }
    });

});
```

//Widget.html

```html
<div class="${baseClass}" data-dojo-attach-point="searchtextbox">
    <p>
        here your widget
    </p>
</div>
```

Problem is the line

`this.emit("customevent",event.x)` is throwing error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Widget events

You should not use `dojo/on` to add event handlers to widgets, it's only for **DOM nodes**. If you extend from `dijit/_WidgetBase` (like you do), then there's a method called [`on()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/_WidgetBase#1_9dijit__WidgetBase_on) which you can use, for example:

```js
myWidget.on("customevent", function(data) {
    console.log( " received notification "+data );
});
```

---

## Widget extension points

I'm not sure what the `emit()` function does, but it seems that here's the problem. According to [the docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#creating-extension-points) you should write your extension points just with plain functions. For example:

```js
postCreate : function () {
    on(this.searchtextbox,"click",lang.hitch(this, "_onClick"));
},
_onClick: function(event) {
    // This is where you put your code
    console.log( "Click event in widget "+event );
    this.onCustomEvent(event.x);
},
onCustomEvent: function() {
     // This can be left empty, it will be used as the extension point
}
```

In this case you will bind the click event to the `_onClick()` function, which in turn calls `onCustomEvent()` with the correct arguments. This function is for public use and can be used to bind custom event handlers.

Here is the [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/q5Gh7/).

Comment: i have changed the listener code as below `code`mywidget.on("customevent",function(data){
            console.log( " received notification "+data );
        });`code` still not working :(

Comment: It seems the `emit()` function is throwing an error. I'm not sure what that function does, but in the docs they're using a different way of creating custom events. I updated my answer with a small howto.

Answer (score 1):

Second param of emit method should be an object, but i was not sending object to it.

```
sendEvent : function(event)
        {
            console.log( "Click event in widget "+event );
            this.emit("customevent",**event**)
        }
```