# dojo custom widget onshow event howto

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

following my code for a custom widget.
Everything works fine except for the event "onShow".

Is there a way to add the event "onShow" to custom widgets?

Thanks!

**CLASS:**

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare","dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin"
,"dojo/text!./templates/testWidget2.html"
],
function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin
    ,template
){
return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {

    templateString: template,

    onShow: function() {
        console.info("testW2 onShow")
    }         

});
});
```

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<div class="${baseClass}" style="border:solid 1px green;">
<h1>W2</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848877/custom-event-is-not-triggered-on-dojo-widget) link for adding custom events to custom widgets.

Comment: The link does not answer my question, unfortunately. 
What I need should already be present as inherited from _widgetBase but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
this.inherited(arguments)
```

in postCreate and startup part of declare.

As in:

```
startup: function(){
  trace("startup"); // helps you trace it in the console
  this.inherited(arguments);
}
```